# DRBD "Device or resource busy"

Tags: centos7, cluster, drbd, pacemaker

So today I've been asked to configure a cluster on Centos7 using pacemaker and drbd.

Everything was going fine until I tried to create a the local meta data for my resource ( a simple web server).

The output of my

> drbdadm create-md wwwdata

command left me a bit puzzled.

> open(/dev/centos_rick/drbd-demo) failed: Device or resource busy

being me I tried to force through with:

> Exclusive open failed. Do it anyways? [need to type 'yes' to confirm]

And just ended up with an error:

> Command 'drbdmeta 1 v08 /dev/centos_rick/drbd-demo internal create-md'
>   terminated with exit code 20

Does anyone have an idea of why i'm confronted to this.

DRBD configuration:

```
resource wwwdata { 
   protocol C; 
   meta-disk internal; 
   device /dev/drbd1; 
   syncer { 
      verify-alg sha1; 
   } 
   net { 
      allow-two-primaries; 
   } 
   on rick { 
      disk /dev/centos_rick/drbd-demo; 
      address 192.168.1.60:7789; 
   } 
   on summer { 
      disk /dev/centos_summer/drbd-demo; 
      address 192.168.1.61:7789; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Try to unmount your device, destroy any partition table etc. on your disks and recreate the MD. Your complete DRBD config would help, too.

Comment: resource wwwdata {
 protocol C;
 meta-disk internal;
 device /dev/drbd1;
 syncer {
  verify-alg sha1;
 }
 net {
  allow-two-primaries;
 }
 on rick {
  disk /dev/centos_rick/drbd-demo;
  address 192.168.1.60:7789;
 }
 on summer {
  disk /dev/centos_summer/drbd-demo;
  address 192.168.1.61:7789;
 }
}

Comment: So that's my config file along with the global_common.conf, i'll get on deleting the partitions and come back to you

Answer (score 2):

Something is holding the backing disk open preventing DRBD from being able to create the meta-data on it. Make sure the device isn't mounted, then try recreating your metadata:

`# umount /dev/centos_rick/drbd-demo && drbdadm create-md wwwdata`

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have a running process (or processes) running on the current active drbd node.

run the following command to show which processes are running

lsof /dev/drbd0

and kill the processes then umount the filesystem on the active node and mount on the secondary node.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the drbd service on the nodes.

systemctl stop drbd

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain further how this will solve the problem.